# CSS grid | How to autofit columns of different sizes?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to utilize CSS grid (for the first time), I'm struggling with some basic problems.

I'm building a footer with three components.

```
  #footer-content {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    max-width: $max-width;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 12% 12% 76%;
}
```

For mobile:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #footer-content {
      grid-template-columns: 50% 50% 100%;
    }
}
```

The problem with above code: The third element (width 100%) is not pushed to next line but appears out of the screen.

Using `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 50% 50% 100%);` does not work.

Using `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 50%);` works: the third element is pushed down **but** is only 50% width instead of 100%.

**Question:** How can I use the CSS grid to auto-fit three columns of different sizes?

Comment: simply define only one column `grid-template-columns: auto;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grid-columns don't wrap so this `grid-template-columns: 50% 50% 100%;` makes no sense for **two** columns. You would define TWO columns and tell the third element to span them both on the following row.

```css
.box {
  height: 150px;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

#footer-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-gap: .25em;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer-content">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```